# Equivalent definition of trace-class operators?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $H$ be a separable complex Hilbert space and $T\in\mathcal{B}(H)$. Let $\{v_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an orthonormal basis for $H$. Then $T$ is of trace class if
$$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\langle |T|v_i,v_i\rangle_H<\infty,$$
where $|T|$ is defined to be $\sqrt{T^*T}$. For such an operator, its trace is defined to be
$$\text{tr}(T):=\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\langle Tv_i,v_i\rangle_H,$$
which one can show is an absolutely convergent series.

**Question:** Suppose the series
$$\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}\langle Tv_i,v_i\rangle_H$$
is absolutely convergent for every orthonormal basis $\{v_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. Then is $T$ of trace class?

Comment: By the way, this means that it is sufficient to assume that the series converges for every ONB (without requiring it to converge absolutely) by Riemann's rearrangement theorem.

Comment: Ah, good point!